# Как правильно разбить JSON на части и поочередно отправлять каждую часть по AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Подскажите как правильно разбить JSON на части (по 1000 значений),

и поочередно отправлять каждую часть по AJAX ?

```js
// допустим здесь 1000000 значений
let json = '[{"name":"Иван", "age":25},{"name":"Петя", "age":35},{"name":"Коля", "age":45}]';

$('button').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {data: json},
    success: function(data){}
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Импорт</button>
```

Comment: "здесь 1000000 значений" - значений чего? это массив?

Comment: @Igor, да, отобразил в примере

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let data = JSON.parse(json);
  var tosend = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tosend.push(data[i]);
    if (tosend.length == 1000 || i == data.length - 1) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {data: tosend},
        success: function(data){}
      });
      tosend = [];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: + если важен порядок -- посылать `i` рядом с `{data:`; + подумать про обработку ошибок